# Im getting an error for firebase's signInWithCredential

Tags: firebase, expo

In my expo react native app, I use firebase and expo to authenticate. But when I try to run signInWithCredential, I get this error for Apple auth. `[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'credential._getIdTokenResponse')]`

Here is my code.

```
const signInWithApple = () => {
  const nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);

  return Crypto.digestStringAsync(Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256, nonce)
      .then((hashedNonce) =>
          AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
              requestedScopes: [
                  AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
                  AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL
              ],
              nonce: hashedNonce
          })
      )
      .then((appleCredential) => {
          const { identityToken } = appleCredential;
          const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com')
          const credential = provider.credential({
              idToken: identityToken,
              rawNonce: nonce
          });
          
          return signInWithCredential(credential); // Line causing error
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error.

Instead of `signInWithCredential(credential)`, I put `signInWithCredential(auth,credential)`.

I also added a service ID in the firebase console.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I will add that you also have to await it in firebase sdk version 9 (modular), or use a .then:

 signInWithCredential(auth, credential).then(userCredential => {
         //Do things with the userCredential.user
        });